# Exceptions in java with vectors and iterators

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, vector, iterator

I have the following piece of code. I would like to know what sort of exceptions would be caught inside the catch block in a multithreaded enviorment.

```
class Goo
{
private Vector objects = new Vector();

public void kempute ()
{
    Iterator iter = objects.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        try {
            Object o = (Object)iter.next();
            System.out.println(o.hashCode());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            //
        }
    }
}

public void addme (Object o)
{
    objects.add(o);
}
}
```

I really couldnt find any exceptions. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception could be caught at that point if

```
Object o = (Object)iter.next();
```

or

```
System.out.println(o.hashCode());
```

throw an unchecked exception.  Here are a couple of possibilities:

- If you had previously called `addObject(null)`, a call to `update()` would lead to a NullPointerException when it calls `hashCode()` on a `null` reference.
- If you have an instance of `Foo` shared by two threads, and one calls `addObject` while the other is calling `compute()`, then you could get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
- If `Vector` was a custom class and not `java.util.Vector`, then `iter.next()` could throw some other unchecked exception ... at the whim of the author of said custom class.  (OK ... unlikely in the light of the OP's comments.)
- (From aix's answer) - `o.hashCode()` could in theory throw any unchecked exception, depending on how `o`'s class implements the `hashCode()` method.
- There may be other possibilities too.

---

If you are merely curious as to what the possible exceptions might be, the above more or less covers it.

If you want to tidy up this code, then it is probably a bad thing to be catching `Exception` at that point.  Each of those cases listed is a sign of a bug here or elsewhere in the application.  Rather that catching the exception at that point and (presumably) trying to "make good" the problem, it is better to bomb out with a stacktrace, and then go back and *fix* the root problem that was being hidden by the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may throw [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) in a multithreaded environment where one or more threads may add or remove element from the list and other thread may iterate it simultaneously .

From [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) JavaDoc :

> The iterators returned by this class's **iterator** and **listIterator**
>   methods are **fail-fast**: if the vector is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   **ConcurrentModificationException**. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future. The Enumerations returned by the elements method are
>   not fail-fast.

Answer (score 0):

Two operations can potentially raise an exception:

1. `o.hashCode()` could throw a `RuntimeException`.
2. `iter.next()` could also throw a `RuntimeException`, such as `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Remember that anything derived from `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception, and does not need to be declared on the `throws` clause.

P.S. Why are you still using `Vector` and not, say, `ArrayList`?

Comment: Well basically this is a very old piece of code that we are maintaining, thats why the Vector. Could you be more specific on the RuntimeException for o.hashcode()?

Comment: Well, we don't know what's in that `Vector`. For example, it could contain an object whose `hashCode` has a bug in it that intermittently accesses an out-of-bounds array element. When this happens, the JVM will automatically raise an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and your method will catch it.

Answer (score -2):

No exception will be through out .
Vector is thread safe class,so don't worry about the multithreaded enviorment

Comment: (-1) This is really bad advice: (a) `Vector` is explicitly documented to throw ConcurrentModificationException; (b) you are misunderstanding what is meant by Vector being thread-safe.